# Deploying Django, supervisorctl abnormal termination

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

I'm trying to deploy django. So installed everything in a clean VPS. I'm able to run the server using unicorn but I'm trying to use supervisord. So I followed [this](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/) tutorial like I did in the past, but now when i'm starting the app using `sudo supervisorctl start uniprogress` i'm getting an error saying `uniprogress: ERROR (abnormal termination)`. Below you can find the log file.

File:/opt/myapps/logs/gunicorn_supervisor.log

```
Starting uniprogress as uniusr
2014-04-24 04:54:30 [18053] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/myapps/uniprogress/../bin/gunicorn", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('gunicorn==18.0', 'console_scripts', 'gunicorn')()
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 71, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 143, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 172, in run
    self.start()
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 134, in start
    self.LISTENERS = create_sockets(self.cfg, self.log)
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 198, in create_sockets
    sock = sock_type(addr, conf, log)
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 99, in __init__
    os.remove(addr)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/myapps/run/gunicorn.sock'
Starting uniprogress as uniusr
2014-04-24 04:54:31 [18064] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/myapps/uniprogress/../bin/gunicorn", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('gunicorn==18.0', 'console_scripts', 'gunicorn')()
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 71, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 143, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 172, in run
    self.start()
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 134, in start
    self.LISTENERS = create_sockets(self.cfg, self.log)
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 198, in create_sockets
    sock = sock_type(addr, conf, log)
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 99, in __init__
    os.remove(addr)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/myapps/run/gunicorn.sock'
Starting uniprogress as uniusr
2014-04-24 04:54:31 [18064] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/myapps/uniprogress/../bin/gunicorn", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('gunicorn==18.0', 'console_scripts', 'gunicorn')()
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 71, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 143, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 172, in run
    self.start()
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 134, in start
    self.LISTENERS = create_sockets(self.cfg, self.log)
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 198, in create_sockets
    sock = sock_type(addr, conf, log)
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 99, in __init__
    os.remove(addr)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/myapps/run/gunicorn.sock'
Starting uniprogress as uniusr
2014-04-24 04:54:34 [18075] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/myapps/uniprogress/../bin/gunicorn", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('gunicorn==18.0', 'console_scripts', 'gunicorn')()
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 71, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 143, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 172, in run
    self.start()
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 134, in start
    self.LISTENERS = create_sockets(self.cfg, self.log)
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 198, in create_sockets
    sock = sock_type(addr, conf, log)
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 99, in __init__
    os.remove(addr)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/myapps/run/gunicorn.sock'
Starting uniprogress as uniusr
2014-04-24 04:54:37 [18086] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/myapps/uniprogress/../bin/gunicorn", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('gunicorn==18.0', 'console_scripts', 'gunicorn')()
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 71, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 143, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 172, in run
    self.start()
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 134, in start
    self.LISTENERS = create_sockets(self.cfg, self.log)
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 198, in create_sockets
    sock = sock_type(addr, conf, log)
  File "/opt/myapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 99, in __init__
    os.remove(addr)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/myapps/run/gunicorn.sock'
```

Comment: Looks like the user you try to start the process with doesn't have access to write in the folder: `/opt/myapps/run`

Comment: It's the `root` user. Any suggestion on how to allow access to write?

Comment: The use you configured in supervisor not the user that runs supervisor: `Starting uniprogress as uniusr`.

Comment: When you configure the `[program]` in supervisor you specify a user. That is the user which actually runs the process. And should have access to the folder.

Comment: So how will I give write permissions to the user `uniusr`?

Comment: something like `sdo chown -R hello:users /webapps/hello_django` and 
`sudo chmod -R g+w /webapps/hello_django` for example?

Comment: The folder is `/opt/myapps/run`. You should have a group that has write access to that folder. And put the executing users in that group.

Comment: Oh ok! I think i got it now! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was that the user `uniusr` did **not** have permissions to write to `/opt/myapps`. So what I did in order to fix this is the following.

```
sudo chown -R uniusr:users /opt/myapps
sudo chmod -R g+w /opt/myapps
```